# Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting a error message from my laravel program that it tries to access an array offset on value of type null while i was trying to code an foreach loop.

i was coding a foreach loop for an absention dashboard that will run trough a row in the database called aanwezigheid (Dutch Language) then i got the error message Trying to access array offset on value of type null i have tried to update composer.json and adding this line

```
$len = isset($cOTLdata['char_data']) ? count($cOTLdata['char_data']) : 0;
```

into my code that if found here on stack overflow.
i know that the error comes from the line `$aanwezigheid = $row['aanwezigheid'];`

My Code:

```
<?php
    require "dbconnect.php";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM medewerkers LEFT JOIN aanwezigheid ON medewerkers.ID=aanwezigheid.ID;";
    if($result = $conn-> query($sql)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['voornaam']." ".$row['achternaam'];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        $aanwezigheid = $row['aanwezigheid'];
        $aanw[] = $aanwezigheid;
        foreach($aanw as $aanwezigheid){
            if($aanwezigheid == 1){
                echo '<img src="image/kruismark.png">"';
            }elseif($aanwezigheid == 0){
                echo '<img src="image/Checkmark.png">"';
            }
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to access $row outside the while ? $row will be the last row at that point. Also i don't see anything related to laravel in that code, you should not query the database yourself in laravel, but use the query builder or eloquent. And also you should not have procedural php code like that.

Comment: thank you for your response i have tried to access the $row inside the while but then it becomes an almost infitite loop and i get back 3546 values

Comment: Well because you have multiple rows in your table, if you need a subset of that you will need to add a where condition on your query

Comment: i see, i mixed up row and column. anyway Thanks for the help man